# npm install serve-static is not working, what to do?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am trying to install serve-static using following command:

> npm install serve-static

I get the following response:

```
serve-static@1.11.1 node_modules\serve-static
├── escape-html@1.0.3
├── encodeurl@1.0.1
├── parseurl@1.3.1
└── send@0.14.1 (destroy@1.0.4, fresh@0.3.0, range-parser@1.2.0, etag@1.7.0, ms@
0.7.1, statuses@1.3.0, debug@2.2.0, depd@1.1.0, mime@1.3.4, on-finished@2.3.0, h
ttp-errors@1.5.0)
```

I believe serve-static installation failed. What I am doing wrong? My Node version is 4.5.0 and npm version is 2.15.9.

Comment: Why would you think it failed? It shows it right there in the output you've shown.

Comment: @mscdex thanks, I was mistaken.It actually works.